# Elasticsearch: monotonically decreasing number of results in the number of search terms, but not zero

Tags: elasticsearch

What is the best way of tuning ElasticSearch so that the number of results are monotically decreasing in the number of search terms, not yielding zero results if possible?

For example if you would search for "test bla blup" and you would have an entity with "test bla", one with "test" and one with "bla blup" you would still get something.

However "test" would yield two and "test bla" one result.

Of course you could do two searches if the first yields nothing, is there a better way?

My colleague and I experimented with the and operator, minimum should match, minimum score and the type of the multi_match clause, but it is not really satisfying.

"It should feel like google"

Thank you for your attention

Comment: What do you expect when you search for string "test bla blup"? 0 results or all 3 ?

Comment: At least one result (the exact number is undefined). Reason is that there are still somewhat relevant results.

Comment: If so, then a search on "test bla" would also produce the docs having "test" and "bla blup" as they are also somewhat relevant. Or do you want this sort of 'relevant results' only when there's no result for the exact match "test bla"?

Comment: Perhaps you should use a [match_phrase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/phrase-matching.html#phrase-matching) query which essentially matches if the words appear together in the document. If this doesn't fetch you any results, then execute a simple match query to show the relevant results. That's all I could think of as of now :(

Comment: Your suggestion is similar to what we use right now. The main thing I am interested in is if there is a "Google" default close to what google is doing.